# Threads vs exception safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, c++11

After having spent some time writing multithreaded code in C++11, I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if there are some real shortcomings in the standard with respect to exception safety.

My main complaint is related to the fact that most of (all?) the threading primitives can throw during basic operations such as locking, waiting, joining, etc., typically with an `std::system_error` exception. See, for instance:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait

This makes it quite hard to implement constructs such as thread pools or barriers in an exception safe manner, and it leads to code which can look quite convoluted.

Are there some special patterns I am not aware of that make it easier to write exception safe multithreaded code in C++11?

I understand that in normal circumstances errors in threading primitives are going to be quite unlikely, but after having spent so much time making sure everything else is exception-safe it seems a bit of a defeat to throw (ah ah) everything out of the window :)

Comment: Can you show a concrete example (with source code) where you have problems regarding exception safety?

Comment: @nosid: anything that uses a lock and a mutex. A concrete example is a thread barrier: when you call `wait()` and the call fails because the internal locking mechanism throws, you are left with the other threads waiting forever for an event that will never happen.

Comment: This is not a real problem.  These are *vexing* exceptions, if they ever get thrown then the show is over.  You cannot let your program continue running, there isn't any way to recover.  Catch them only for error reporting just before you terminate.

Comment: @HansPassant: that is exactly what I am doing indeed, but it feels a bit like a defeat :/

Comment: Since C++14, at least `std::condition_variable::wait` can´t throw an exception.

Comment: @nosid: right, just saw it on the cppreference page. I took it as an hint that there might be some work going on about this.

Comment: You can call `std::terminate` if the call to `lock` fails. This should solve the exception safety problem.

Comment: If you get such exceptions, there is something badly wrong with your code, lib or OS.  Like @HansPassant says, you are stuffed with no chance of a clean recovery.  Log and exit.